# Batch command tasklist for remote computer

Tags: windows, authentication, cmd, tasklist

i'm trying to use tasklist command in cmd.exe for list all processes on my remote Windows 10 PC (which is in my home and connected on the same network as my main computer).
But when I type in cmd.exe from my main computer `tasklist /s <his IP> /u Lucas /p <Lucas's password>` it shows me `Error : Incorrect user or password` but user Lucas is the local admin for this remote PC and I'm 100% sure it's the right password, I really don't understand.

I have tried to disable firewall for private network, without success.
I have tried to add an exception in the firewall for port 135 (TCP), without success.
Ping command works fine.

I hope you can help me.

Regards.

Comment: Perhaps there are white-spaces or other special characters in the password...

Comment: @aschipfl there is a ! in the password, can be the cause ?

Comment: If [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, yes! If so, try to escape it like `^^!`...

Comment: @aschipfl I forgot to say that I have another user on this remote pc with a simple password and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you specifying the user with `DOMAIN\username` or just `username`?

Comment: Would you be willing to try `powershell -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName LUCAS -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}"`? You can also pass `-Credentials` on Invoke-Command.

Comment: @lit I don't use domain, so I put `local\Lucas` ? And if `local\Lucas` is right, it doesn't work (Lucas is the local admin user of the remote PC).
For powershell command I get `ServerNotTrusted` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by doing `powershell Invoke-Command -ComputerName <ip of the remote computer> -Credential <his_name>\PC_Guest -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}`
with `<his_name>` the name of the remote PC.
For the explanations `PC_Guest` was the old name of the admin account that I renamed to `Lucas` and I think that when we rename administrators accounts, Windows not change completely the name in permissions system, so that is why I had `Access Denied` or `Unknown user or password` errors with user `Lucas`.
Thanks @lit for your answer.

Comment: I would encourage you to use `-NoProfile` on the powershell invocation. If the user's profile ever produces anything to the console, it may disrupt your code.